# Python convert ODS to xlsx in memory

Tags: python, django, opendocument

I have a Django app that generates reports using relatorio ODS templates. The output rendered file is also in ODS format. I would like to be able to convert the output ODS to PDF, XLS, XLSX ..etc.

The only solution I could find was by running LibreOffice as a standalone server or using libreoffice in headless mode.

Is there a library that can help me with the conversion to avoid dealing with files and avoid running LibreOffice all the time on my server? What dependencies would it introduce ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have style and charts in ods? do you want to convert style and charts to xlsx too?

Comment: Simple styles like font sizes, no charts at all.